# Single value binding in aspx page

Tags: c#, asp.net, data-binding

I need to populate an aspx page with dozens of properties from a db query. What I know how to do is to assign the property to the Text attribute of the control in the code behind like this:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string param = Request.QueryString["param"];
    // p will have dozens of properties
    M.P p = new M.P(param);
    aLabel.Text = p.aProperty;
    anotherLabel.Text = p.anotherProperty;
```

And in the aspx code:

```
<asp:Label ID="aLabel" runat="server"></asp:Label>
<asp:Label ID="anotherLabel" runat="server"></asp:Label>
```

What I would like to do is to just bind the properties directly in the aspx page without the need to the assignment in the code behind like this:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string param = Request.QueryString["param"];
    M.P p = new M.P(param);
    this.DataBind();

Value of the aProperty: <%# p.aProperty %>
Value of the anotherProperty: <%# p.anotherProperty #>
```

But I'm missing something important as the compiler gives me the error `The name 'p' does not exist in the current context`. How to make it work?

Comment: Note: Don't use `asp:Label` unless they're actually labels. See http://haacked.com/archive/2007/02/15/asp.net_tip_-_use_the_label_control_correctly.aspx

Comment: @mo. Indeed I eliminated the labels with the help of the accepted answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could have something like this (`p` moved as property)

**C#**

```
protected M.P p {get; set;}

protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string param = Request.QueryString["param"];
    p = new M.P(param);
}
```

**ASPX**

```
<asp:Label ID="aLabel" runat="server"><%= p.aProperty %></asp:Label>
<asp:Label ID="anotherLabel" runat="server"><%= p.anotherProperty %></asp:Label>
```

Comment: It seems the `DataBind()` is obligatory so I added it to your answer.

Comment: @Clodoaldo: DataBind is not necessary for making my code work. If something is failing let me know and we can sort it out.

Comment: @Clodoaldo: I don't know if you have any other code requiring databindd but this simple code doesn't require it. Anyway, glad it worked.

Comment: You are right. I was using `<%#` in instead of `<%=` as in your markup.