# Binding single value to aspx page

Tags: c#, asp.net

Trying to bind a value in code behind to aspx page.

```
<div>
   <table>
        <tr>
          <th>Item</th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td><asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("ItemId")%>'/></td>   
         </tr>
   </table> 
 </div>
```

Code behind:

```
int ItemId = 3;
```

NOTE: I have tried:

```
<%=ItemId%> AND <%:ItemId%>
```

But no joy! What am I doing wrong? All I want to do is to bind to a single value.

Comment: And what happens? Do you get an error message or is the text of Label1 just blank. In your codebehind do you do Label1.Text = ItemID; (which would make your eval statement unneccessary)?

Comment: Check this out:- http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11366274/single-value-binding-in-aspx-page

Answer (score 2):

```
<asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text='<%# ItemId %>'/>
```

This is the proper format on the page, but you also need to execute a data binding event in your codebehind:

```
int ItemId = 3;
this.DataBind();
```

Although philreed has it right that since you are already using a label, you might as well just update the `label.Text` property with your value, rather than go through the data binding process.  Using the `<%# ItemId %>` is best for when you want to stick a random data value in the middle of regular page markup, not an ASP control, like so:

```
<div>
    The number you picked is <%# ItemId %>.
</div>
```

It still needs the `DataBind()` in your codebehind when doing this.

Answer (score 1):

If its only ever the single value, why not use this in your code behind?

```
Label1.Text = ItemId.ToString();
```

and remove the `<%# Eval("ItemId")%>` from your markup.

Answer (score 0):

```
<asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text='<%# ItemId %>'/>
```